# How do i hide a div on click of button for particular case

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There are four fields in the form.

And two buttons i.e next and ok .
Next button is to jump from one field to another. 
And there is ok button to skip all the fields i.e it hides the div that I want to .

But what I want is, that when the user is on fourth field i.e is last one, and the user clicks NEXT button it should hide the div.

This is the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h2wvgazs/3/)

This is the code:

```
<main>
      <div class="welcome-form">
        <img src="img/form-bg.png" alt="" class="img-responsive bg-image">
        <div class="form-overlay">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="launching-div">
              <h1 class="orange-text">Boom!</h1>
              <p>That’s all we needed from you to get started hold on tight.....</p>
            </div>
            <div class="form-inner">
              <h1>Welcome to Shoprocket</h1>
              <p>If your new to shoprocket we need to ask you <span class="orange-text">4 simple questions</span> to help us optimise your account. If your a regular feel free to skip this bit, you know the drill...</p>
              <form method="post">
                <div class="form-step-wrapper">
                  <hr>
                  <div class="form-step">
                    <div class="active"></div>
                    <div></div>
                    <div></div>
                    <div></div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-main">

                  <ul style="display: block;" class="form-content">
                    <li>
                      <h2><span class="orange-text">1.</span> tell us your email</h2>
                    </li>
                    <li class="form-group">
                      <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Type it in here" data-required="true" data-email="true" class="form-control">
                    </li>
                  </ul>

                  <ul style="display: none;" class="form-content">
                    <li><h2><span class="orange-text">2.</span>what are you selling?</h2></li>
                    <li class="form-group">
                      <select data-required="true" name="option" class="selectpicker" multiple>
                        <option value="" disabled>Pick the ones that apply to you</option>
                        <option value="1">Shipping / post</option>
                        <option value="2">Customers can collect</option>
                        <option value="3">Other</option>
                      </select>
                    </li>
                  </ul>

                  <ul style="display: none;" class="form-content">
                    <li><h2><span class="orange-text">3.</span>how will you fulfill orders?</h2></li>
                    <li class="form-group" >
                      <select data-required="true" name="option" class="selectpicker" multiple>
                        <option value="" disabled>Pick the ones that apply to you</option>
                        <option value="1">Shipping / post</option>
                        <option value="2">Customers can collect</option>
                        <option value="3">Other</option>
                      </select>
                    </li>
                  </ul>

                  <ul style="display: none;" class="form-content">
                    <li><h2><span class="orange-text">4.</span>where is your collection from?</h2></li>
                    <li class="form-group" >
                      <select data-required="true" name="option" class="selectpicker" multiple>
                        <option value="" disabled>Pick the ones that apply to you</option>
                        <option value="1">Shipping / post</option>
                        <option value="2">Customers can collect</option>
                        <option value="3">Other</option>
                      </select>
                    </li>
                  </ul>

                </div>

                <div class="form-navigation">
                  <span id="sf-msg" class="sf-msg-error"></span>
                  <button id="sf-prev" class="sf-button" type="button" style="display: none">Previous</button>
                  <button id="sf-next" class="sf-button" type="button">next</button>
                  <button id="sf-ok" type="button" class="sf-button">ok</button>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
```

This is the js code that I use to hide the div

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#sf-ok").click(function(e) {
        $(".form-inner").hide();
    $(".launching-div").show();
});
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the way you want to do. Use following in your jquery code.

```
if(t.active == 3){
    $(".form-inner").hide();
    $(".launching-div").show();
 }
```

Check [Fiddle Here.](http://jsfiddle.net/h2wvgazs/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Better to do lots of code, you can simply use

http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples